# Why Tomcat is Killed?

Tags: linux, java, tomcat

In Linux system which is an host account, Tomcat is Killed after start up and sometime middle of start up, it happens automatically. No log is shown, just **Killed** message is displayed.

What could be the cause and solution ?

I am configuring java app for client and do not have direct access for hosting provider to ask or query.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Update:**
It seems like Tomcat service is killed by hosting server itself it reaches to maximum Server Load / Memory Used.

Is there any way to configure Tomcat to use less memory or resources ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any log messages? It's impossible to diagnose the issue with the current (little) information.

Comment: The problem is there is no log message, I looked in to the catalina.out too, there is nothing. just **Killed** message is displayed.

Comment: @slhck I have updated the question, can you help now ? Thanks